# How to install the IIS in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, iis-7

I have tried to install IIS in My local machine in windows 7. My purpose is to install the IIS & change its Seesion timeout property because I want to increase the Session time out Period. So I went to `Control Panel` -> `All Control Panel Items` -> `Programs and Features` then clicked Windows features on & off.

After that clicked on Internet Information Service then Web Management Tool then IIS Management Console then pressed ok.

It installed but when I went to see in `Inetpub\wwwroot` I got nothing. When I went to see 
http://localhost  result shows blank page.

I tried to search in Google but still I didn't get the answer. So please help me sort out this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you actually install IIS itself instead of just the management console.
Windows Features -> IIS -> World Wide Web-services

Or use the Web Platform installer like Snake said.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Web Platform](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx?wt.mc_id=bac-web-corp-BBWS_mscom_WebPI) installer, this will do most of the stuff for you. You might have forgotten something.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: [Configure Windows 7 IIS7 for ISAPI DLL](http://chee-yang.blogspot.com/2009/10/configure-windows-7-iis7-for-isapi-dll.html)